# Unit testing ApiController methods with status codes not in HttpStatusCode enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq

I have an ApiController method that looks like this...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] GloballyEnumeratedMessage gem)
    {
        var result = _gemPublisher.PublishGem(gem);

        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        return new StatusCodeResult((HttpStatusCode)422, this);
    }
```

My test for for checking the Ok result is as follows.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Post_ValidGem_Returns200()
    {
        _gemPublisherMock.Setup(v => v.PublishGem(It.IsAny<GloballyEnumeratedMessage>())).Returns(ResultStatus.FromSuccess());

        var controller = new PublishGemController(_gemPublisherMock.Object);

        // Act
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Post(It.IsAny<GloballyEnumeratedMessage>());

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(OkResult));
    }
```

Before I was returning a 422, I was returning a BadRequest and the test looked like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Post_InvalidGem_Returns400()
    {
        _gemPublisherMock.Setup(v => v.PublishGem(It.IsAny<GloballyEnumeratedMessage>())).Returns(ResultStatus.FromFailure());

        var controller = new PublishGemController(_gemPublisherMock.Object);

        // Act
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Post(It.IsAny<GloballyEnumeratedMessage>());

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(BadRequestResult));
    }
```

I wanted to reserve BadRequest for another potential failure so decided to change the Post method to return a 422 if the Publish fails. What would my test to check for the 422 status code look like?

EDIT: Solved based off a comment to the question

```
[TestMethod]
public void Post_InvalidGem_Returns422()
{
    _gemPublisherMock.Setup(v => v.PublishGem(It.IsAny<GloballyEnumeratedMessage>())).Returns(ResultStatus.FromFailure());

    var controller = new PublishGemController(_gemPublisherMock.Object);

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Post(It.IsAny<GloballyEnumeratedMessage>());
    var result = (StatusCodeResult) actionResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(StatusCodeResult));
    Assert.AreEqual(422, (int)result.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: Can you not verify that the result is an `StatusCodeResult` and it contains the status 422?

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that? Something like: 
            `var contentResult = actionResult as StatusCodeResult;
            Assert.AreEqual(422, (int)contentResult.StatusCode);` ?

Comment: Submit this as the solution and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following controller and test do what I believe what you want to accomplish:

Controller:

```
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] object gem)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult((HttpStatusCode)422, this);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Post_Returns422()
    {
        var controller = new MyTestController();

        // Act
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Post(It.IsAny<object>());

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(StatusCodeResult));
        Assert.AreEqual((int)((StatusCodeResult)actionResult).StatusCode,422);
    }
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track but actionResult doesn't have that property.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer accordingly.